# Вывод сообщений с функций exit и echo файла скрипта при выполнении асинхронной фунуции

Tags: ajax, php

**Подключен фреймворк**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scriptjava.net/source/scriptjava/scriptjava.js"></script>
```

**Есть форма**

```
<form id="form-to-login" action="/account/authorization/login.php" method="post">
   <div class="lable">Логин</div>
   <input name="login" class="form" type="text" maxlength="20">
   <div class="lable">Пароль</div>
   <input name="password" class="form" type="password" maxlength="20">
   <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Войти" onclick="SendForm();">
</form>
```

**После идет вызов асинхронной функции**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function SendForm() {
      //отправка файла на сервер
      $$f({
         formid:'form-to-login',//id формы
         url:'/account/authorization/login.php',//адрес на серверный скрипт, такой же как и в форме
         onstart:function () {//действие при начале отправки
            $$('result','начинаю отправку');//в элемент с id="result" выводим результат
         },
         onsend:function () {//действие по окончании отправки
            $$('result',$$('result').innerHTML+'<br />комментарий успешно отправлен');//в элемент с id="result" выводим результат
         }
      });
   }
</script>
//выводим сообщение
<span id="result"></span>
```

**Скрипт обработки данных полученных из формы(login.php)**

```
<?php
   //заносим введенные логин и пароль в переменные и шифруем пароль.
   if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} }
   if (isset($_POST['password'])) { md5($password=$_POST['password']); if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }   
  //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт.
   if (empty($login) or empty($password)) {
     exit ("Вы не заполнили все поля!");
   }
   //если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести.
   $login = stripslashes($login);
   $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
   $password = stripslashes($password);
   $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
   //удаляем лишние пробелы.
   $login = trim($login);
   $password = trim($password);
   // подключаемся к базе.
   include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/access/db.php');
   //извлекаем из базы все данные о пользователе с введенным логином.
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
   $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   if (empty($myrow['password'])) {
      //если пользователя с введенным логином не существует.
      exit ("Не верный логин или пароль!");
   }
   else {
      //если существует, то сверяем пароли.
      if ($myrow['password']==$password) {
         //если пароли совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию.
         $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['login']; 
         $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id'];
         $_SESSION['admin']=$myrow['admin'];
         echo "Вы успешно вошли на сайт!";
      }
      else {
         //если пароли не сошлись.
         echo ("Не верный логин или пароль!");
      }
   }
?>
```

**Собственно вопрос:** *как вывести сообщения с функций exit и echo в span result на странице с формой без перезагрузки страницы?*

Comment: что такое `$$f` и `$$` ? а понятно, некая scriptjava...

Answer (score 3):

Согласно документации на вашу странную библиотеку:

```
//отправляю запрос и получаю ответ
$$a({
  url:'ajax.php',
  data:{'q':'1'},
  success:function (data) {
    $$('result',data);
  }
});
```

это значит что data вам приходит в виде аргумента функции привязанной к succes.

делаем вывод:

```
$$f({
         formid:'form-to-login',//id формы
         url:'/account/authorization/login.php',//адрес на серверный скрипт, такой же как и в форме
//         onstart:function () {//действие при начале отправки
            $$('result','начинаю отправку');//в элемент с id="result" выводим результат// не вижу в доке никаких onstart
         },
         success:function (data) {//действие по окончании отправки
            $$('result',$$('result').innerHTML+data);//в элемент с id="result" выводим результат
         }
      });
```

у меня есть вопрос. почему вы выбрали ScriptJava и почему раз вы его выбрали вы не можете **прочитать документацию самостоятельно** ?

ps: время от времени при нажатии по ссылкам на сайте scriptjava мне выкидывает рекламу во всплывающих страницах... короче там рекомендуют в блоге написать... вот моя запись - ненужный напыщеный лисопед.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На самом деле я профан еще в делах асинхронной передачи данных. ScriptJava - первое на что попал. Если вам не трудно, посоветуйте что-то получше и с более точной документацией.

Comment: @batxed, если вы собираетесь заниматься этим и впредь, то начать желательно с азов JavaScript. А из библиотек, основанных на JS, каждый второй вам посоветует [jQuery][1] ([документация на русском][2] **не полная!**, посему на официальный сайт заглядывать обязательно)

   [1]:http://jquery.com/
   [2]:http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0